# "Take advantage" vs. "make advantage"

Tags: word-choice, verbs, connotation, collocation

I'm worried that 'take advantage' could have a slightly negative connotation. Could you say "make advantage [of a situation]"?

Comment: Or you could turn a situation to your advantage.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with *take advantage* per se.  If I said, "Airline fares are only discounted through Sunday, so make sure you take advantage of that when getting your tickets for this summer."  There's no negative connotation whatsoever.  In fact everyone will look favorably on you when you tell them how much you paid. So if it's not a "negative situation" go ahead and use *take advantage*.  In a situation in which *take advantage* is negative, rephrasing it won't help: "*I took advantage of the shopkeeper's distraction and pocketed a candy bar*" isn't changed by using *made the most of*

Comment: @Jim I am writing a document where the idea of "taking advantage of somebody's naivety" is already being suggested.

Comment: @FumbleFingers In what reference work can you look up the absence of an expression?

Comment: @MετάEd: Okay, maybe "no-one" was putting it a bit strong. There's one [which **makes** advantage of](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22which+makes+advantage+of%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) in Google Books. But that's up against 225,000 instances of [which **takes** advantage of](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22which+takes+advantage+of%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). As to citing a reference work to back me up on that, I couldn't be bothered even if there was one. Are you seriously going to *defend* the usage in the absence of specific instructions not to?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Languages are productive. You can come up with a sentence nobody has used before and be perfectly well understood. A person could say "make advantage" and be understood. However I would not for a moment claim it's a common or idiomatic expression. But you are missing my point: General Reference as a close reason means the person plainly failed to look it up in any work of general reference, *because it's found there*.

Comment: @MετάEd: I've only got the closevote reasons they provide us with here. Because OP here mistakenly thinks "take advantage" has negative connotations, he's got this bizarre idea of trying an (effectively random) change of a single letter, to solve a non-existent problem. Evolution might work like that, but language doesn't. Not to mention which there's no real future in *non-native speakers* trying to "improve" non-existent shortcomings in English. Anyway, I don't care what specific closevote reason applies. It's a rubbish question.

Comment: Then it's not constructive, or off topic (writing advice). Don't dilute general reference. It's already misused too much.

Answer (score 5):

No, but you could "make the most" of a situation.

Comment: to me this suggests that things are sub-optimal.