# Take advantage of this opportunity

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-usage

I find myself recurrently stopped while writing e-mails for a main purpose (e.g, answering a direct question from a previous mail somebody sent me) and wanting to add a second theme "taking advantage that I'm already writing you".

I don't want to be rude, in my native language this wouldn't be offensive if one writes something like "I take advantage that you've written me", but "taking advantage" seems awkward in english.

Both links below show some advices but not exactly in the context I'm looking for.

[Take advantage of - positively](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/120214/take-advantage-of-positively)

["Take advantage" vs. "make advantage"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/101428/take-advantage-vs-make-advantage)

A workaround I'm using is include a separate paragraph with some connector or another phrase (e.g, "I was about to get in touch with you because...") but I would like to understand if this is the only way (the other way is more natural for me).

**UPDATE**

Another example came to my mind. It could happen during a class where a student asks about theme A and the teacher "takes advantage of the question" for clarifying A,B,C or whatever.

Comment: I am guessing you are talking about e-mail. One can write (after paragraph break) "As long as I'm e-mailing you, I should mention that . . ." or "I wanted to get your opinion on . . ." or whatever. But it is in the nature of e-mail, even more than snail-mail, that the addressee is likely to ignore such addenda that are outside the scope of the initial missive.

Comment: @BrianDonovan I'm sorry, it could be cultural but I can't agree with "it is in the nature of e-mail, even more than snail-mail, that the addressee is likely to ignore such addenda that are outside the scope of the initial missive". If someone writes me and opens a second thread It's almost for sure that I'll continue that thread.

Comment: You may formulate your concern this way: "Moreover, I would like to take the opportunity to address ...".